# R integrate over values

Tags: r

I have been trying to integrate the following function over r in `[0,1]`, but to no avail:

```
brownian_bridge <- function(r){X[r*(length(X)-1)+1]-r*X[length(X)]}
```

X is a vector of length 1000, and r is defined as

```
r=seq(from=0,to=1,length=1000)
```

Furthermore,

```
X=cumsum(rnorm(1000,mean=0,sd=sqrt(1/1000)))
```

Now my question is: How can I integrate browian_bridge over r in [0,1]? Is there a built-in R function to do this? Standard tools such as integrate2() don't seem to work, because r is a sequence and not a function that holds for all r in [0,1].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should use `Vectorize` first and then apply `integrate`

```
f <- Vectorize(brownian_bridge,"r")
res <- integrate(f,0,1,subdivisions = 1e5)
```

such that

```
set.seed(1)
X=cumsum(rnorm(1000,mean=0,sd=sqrt(1/1000)))
brownian_bridge <- function(r){
  X[r*(length(X)-1)+1]-r*X[length(X)]
}

f <- Vectorize(brownian_bridge,"r")

res <- integrate(f,0,1,subdivisions = 1e5)
```

gives

```
> res
0.2478581 with absolute error < 1e-04
```